# firebase-admin db.collection() unresolved function or method

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I watched the tutorial for NodeJS + Firestore but i'm stuck new 4:50 mark where i need to type in db.collection.

video: Getting Started with Cloud Firestore with Node.js - Firecast  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z87OZtIYC_0

Steps:

1. create NodeJS project
2. npm install firebase-admin

   ```js
   const admin = require('firebase-admin');

   admin.initializeApp({
      credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault()
   });

   const db = admin.firestore();

   db.collection();
   ```

Error: "unresolved function or method collection()"

Firebase version: firebase-admin": "^5.13.1"

firestore()/db indeed does not have the collections method. what am i missing?

Comment: This may not be the cause of the error you are seeing, but [collection()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Firestore#collection) expects a string argument for the path to the collection.

Comment: well, i can't even get that far since collections isn't even considered a method of admin.firestore()

Answer (score 1):

try below, see if it fix

```
npm install @google-cloud/firestore@0.18.0 --save


import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'; //Firebase Admin SDK
import {CollectionReference, DocumentData, DocumentReference, QuerySnapshot} from '@google-cloud/firestore';

const db = <any> admin.firestore();
const docRef = <DocumentReference> db.collection('col').doc(docId);
```

Answer (score 0):

i found that after adding this package, everything started working.

npm install --save @google-cloud/firestore

Answer (score 0):

What helped me is not to use ES2015 improts and just do require

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
```